# JQuery empty selector and setting values

Tags: jquery

If the following selector has a length of 0

```
$(".my_class")
```

and I try to do `$(".my_class").attr('value', 'test');`

It doesn't cause any errors, but should I be checking the length first? What is considered a best practice?

I have a bunch of properties that may or may not exist and am wondering if it is ok to just set an empty jquery value.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. In fact I think that's one of the great features of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to test for length or anything first because jQuery returns an empty jQuery wrapped object, which is why you are even still able to run the method `.attr()` and it doesn't blow up on you!

This is definitely one of the many reasons jQuery is so powerful and easy to use for develoeprs.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't test the length first, this is as useless as doing

```
if (n>0) {
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
```

In fact, this would precisely be the same thing.